# appium java how to identify help overlay (screen with translucent background)

Tags: appium

I am working on a project using appium java.I want to identify when a help overlay comes and dismiss it automatically.I am able to get the parent element but actually not able to recognize the screen theme so that i can handle it and proceed further when the app is first time installed.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you find an answer ?!